# Why won't the img.src define the source of the img-tag in each "li"?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I want to add an image from Firebase Storage in each "li" in the code below, but only the first li has an image. There is no defined src on the other img tags. No errors in the console, but the picURL of each picture is logged in the console, but it won't apply to the src

Code:

```
var postDocRef = db.collection('posts').doc(uid).collection('userPosts')

postDocRef.get().then(snapshot => {
setupPosts(snapshot.docs)
})

const posts = document.querySelector('.posts');

const setupPosts = (data) => {

    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {

        var docRefIDpost = docRef.id

        const post = doc.data();
        const li = `
        <li>
            <div class="title">${post.title}</div>
            <div class="content">${post.content}</div>
            <img class="img">
        </li>
        `;

        var imgRef = db.collection('posts').doc(uid).collection('userPosts');

        imgRef.get().then(function(snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    
                    const data = doc.data();

                    const picURL = data.picURL

                    console.log(picURL)

                    var img = document.querySelector(".img")

                    img.src = picURL

                })
            } else {

                console.log("PicURL doesn't exist")

            }
            
            })
        html += li
    })

    posts.innerHTML = html;

}
});
```

Comment: You can't query the DOM for an element before it's been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
var img = document.querySelector(".img")
```

Each time this runs, you are loading the first `.img` element from the HTML. What you actually want to do is set the image on the `li` that you are currently building.

The simplest way to fix this is to only add the `img` tag to the `li` inside your loop:

```
const setupPosts = (data) => {

    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {

        var docRefIDpost = docRef.id

        const post = doc.data();
        let li = `
        <li>
            <div class="title">${post.title}</div>
            <div class="content">${post.content}</div>
        `;

        var imgRef = db.collection('posts').doc(uid).collection('userPosts');

        imgRef.get().then(function(snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();

                    const picURL = data.picURL

                    console.log(picURL)

                    var img = document.querySelector(".img")

                    li += `<img class="${picURL}">`;
                })
            } else {
                console.log("PicURL doesn't exist")
            }
            
            })
            li += "</li>";

            html += li
        })

        posts.innerHTML = html;
    }
});
```

---

Updated code:

```
const setupPosts = (data) => {
    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {
        var docRefIDpost = docRef.id

        const post = doc.data();
        let li = `
        <li>
            <div class="title">${post.title}</div>
            <div class="content">${post.content}</div>
        `;

        var imgRef = db.collection('posts').doc(uid).collection('userPosts');
        imgRef.get().then(function(snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const picURL = data.picURL

                    var img = document.querySelector(".img")

                    li += `<img class="${picURL}">`;
                })
            } else {
                console.log("PicURL doesn't exist")
            }
            
            li += "</li>";
            html += li
            posts.innerHTML = html;
        })
    })
}
});
```

This updates the HTML after each document is read.

Comment: I got an error now; profile.js:126 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at profile.js:126
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at profile.js:117

Comment: Yeah, the `li` will need to be a regular variable for this to work. I updated my answer, but recommend searching for such problems if you get an error message.

Comment: The img tag is completely removed now. Now it's only the title and content div in the li

Comment: Did you step through the code, and check if it reaches the `li +=` line from my answer? If so, what happens in that line? Stack Overflow is a horribly inefficient interactive debugger, so you'll have to take steps like that yourself if you want us to be able to effectively help.

Comment: Ok, so I went through the code now, and this was printed out as the li: 

```<li>
            <div class="title">asdasd</div>
            <div class="content">asdasdasd</div>
        </li><img class="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/midpoint2-1d3e2.appspot.com/o/posts%2FSkjermbilde42.PNG?alt=media&token=e8970d40-0ef3-479d-866f-9174fb5b4430">

```

So the <img class=".......> is outside the closing li tag (</li>)

Comment: The code is working partly, not as I expected it to do. I want to only have one specific image in the li (the picURL from the document), but it appends all the images in Firebase Storage to the li. So instead of 1 picture per post, I get all the pictures from Firebase Storage into each li. Is there another way to do it, a way that I can get only the picURL image appended to the li and not each picture?

Comment: Your data model allows multiple `userPosts` documents per `post` document. The code simply reflects that data model.  Since each `userPosts` has an image, that means you (can) get multiple images per `post` document, and thus per `li`. If you want to show only one image per `post`, you'll need to decide what `userPosts` to take the image from, and ignore the others. For example, if you want to only use the image of the first `userPosts` of a `posts` document, you can replace the `snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {` loop with `let doc = snapshot.docs[0]` to only process that first doc.

Comment: But ```let doc = snapshot.docs[0]``` only appends the first image in Storage, and not 2 different images (1 unique image per post). I have saved a ```picURL```in Firestore, and I want to retrieve that URL and append the picURL as the src (picURL is a unique image to a post)